# Saving base64 string (bitmap data) from java script on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, bitmap

I have a service that gives the bitmap data in the form of base64 string.

I am using ajax call to get the data from my service into my HTML5 application.

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: MY_SERVICE_URL,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: ImageCaptured,
            error: AjaxFailed
       });
```

"ImageCaptured" method is as follows

```
    var ImgData = "data:image/bmp;base64," + response.serviceResult;
    window.location.href = ImgData;
```

This opens the image. But, my requirement is to save the image locally.

I also tried using

```
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = ImgData;
    link.download = "Image.bmp";
    link.click();
```

This gives me network error.

Am I missing something? Any ideas on how to do so?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I need to open the download dialog for saving the image locally. I am able to display the image in the *img* tag

Comment: Save image locally how exactly? Should the dowload file dialog open, or do you just want to insert an image tag in the HTML ?

Comment: @adeneo: I am able to insert an image tag. I need to open download file dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way out. Hope this helps others.

The change was in "ImageCaptured" function.

```
    var ImgData = "data:image/octet-stream;base64," + response.serviceResult;

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = ImgData;
    link.download = FileName + ".bmp";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```

This downloads the image forcibly from the browser.